# Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.13:wsdl2java

Tags: java, maven, web-services, cxf

I am trying to install a web-app using maven. I see this error that reads:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.13:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project -simple-webapp: Execution generate-sources of goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.13:wsdl2java failed:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are running with invalid JAXP api
>   or implementation. JAXP api/implementation of version 1.3.1 (included
>   in JDK6) or higher is required. In case you are using ant, make sure
>   ant 1.7.0 or higher is used - older versions of ant contain JAXP
>   api/impl version 1.2 (in xml-apis.jar). If you want to keep using
>   older ant versions, you have to configure it to use higher the JAXP
>   api/impl versions.
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
>   -> [Help 1]

The weird part is that I have specified the dependency on jaxp in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is correctly downloaded. I can see that in my .m2 repository. But some how it can still not find.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: To allow reproducing can you paste the full pom?

Comment: @pirho I manage to fix it by changing the POM of the project that was being used in the POM of my code. Weird but somehow it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the following code. I am using JDK8 in my project

```java
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```